# Sorting array by 'order' field that can be undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array:

```
var q = [
    {s: 'last', o: 1000},
    {s: 's2'},
    {s: 's8'},
    {s: 's6'},
    {s: 's1', o: 1},
    {s: 's7'},
    {s: 's9'},
    {s: 's3', o: 3},
    {s: 's5', o: 5},
    {s: 's4', o: 4},
    {s: 's10', o: 10}
]
```

I want to sort it by field q.o, but this field can be undefined.
I need to get result like the example below:

```
var out = [
    {s: 's1', o: 1},
    {s: 's2'},
    {s: 's3', o: 3},
    {s: 's4', o: 4},
    {s: 's5', o: 5},    
    {s: 's8'},
    {s: 's6'},
    {s: 's7'},
    {s: 's9'},
    {s: 's10', o: 10},
    {s: 'last', o: 1000}
]
```

**upd:** 
`s` is an object in real project, it contains scripts to launch. I need to launch all scripts in order as they defined, but before this I need to inject scripts which has `o` field to its places.

Comment: you need to filter it first on property `o` then, if undefined, on property `s`?

Comment: No, property `s` is an array or object. I need to sort if first by index, and then by `o` field.

Comment: in your example, `out[1]` has no property `o` and it's placed before `out[2]`. How do you define that `o: undefined` comes before `o: 3`?

Comment: what do u mean sort by index?

Comment: look you are already sorting it through **S** ,s1,o:1||s3,o:3,||s4,o:4

Comment: Just imagine that we removed all object with `o` field, and got array like this:

    var q = [
        {s: 's2'},
        {s: 's8'},
        {s: 's6'},
        {s: 's7'},
        {s: 's9'}
        ]
after that we put rest of array to places that defined in `o`.

Comment: What if the array is `[ { s: "dog", o: 7 }, { s: "cat" }, { s: "mouse" } ]`? How does the `o` change the position of the dog? Your problem statement is ambiguous. Please explain the rule that `o` follows.

Comment: Element that contains field `o` which is bigger than array length, must be at the end of array. 
If we have two or more elements with big `o` field, we need to sort them themselves

Comment: What if two elements have the same o? Where do elements without an o go? What if o is negative or a fraction? I think you're saying that elements go at the position specified by o, and the other elements are sorted by s and fill in the gaps.

Comment: Oh, in one minute I will write some examples

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ukiWtLnj

Comment: `o` can be only positive integer or undefined.
`o` can't be same for two or more elements. 
In `s` can be anything: object, callback, undefined, etc.

Comment: You said that `o` can't be the same for two or more elements, but your pastebin gives several elements the same value 6 for `o`. And why does `addCat` come before `init`? `a` comes before `i`. I think your problem is that you haven't clearly defined the problem. Until you know what the problem is, you can't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
var out = [];

var a1 = [],
    a2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
    if (q[i].o) {
        a1.push(q[i]);
    } else {
        a2.push(q[i]);
    }
}
a1.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.o - b.o;
});

var aux = a1[0].o;
while (a1.length || a2.length) {
    if ((a1.length && a1[0].o == aux) || a2.length == 0) {
        if(a1[1] && a1[1].o > a1[0].o) aux++;
        out.push(a1.shift());
    } else if(a2.length) {
        out.push(a2.shift());
        aux++;
    }
}
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gTbfW/)

Comment: @rndm so how will you know how to order the ones that does not have `o` property? May they go to the end? If not there should be another order condition

Comment: Just imagine that we removed all object with o field, and got array like this: var q = [ {s: 's2'}, {s: 's8'}, {s: 's6'}, {s: 's7'}, {s: 's9'} ] after that we put rest of array to places that defined in o.

Sorry, I can't explain well what exactly I need because of my bad English

Comment: @rndm I changed my answer and added another DEMO. See if it is this what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works.
I wrote similar code today and now think how to opimize it

Comment: oops, sorry, I'll fix it

Answer (score 0):

Use [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#sortBy) and use the sortBy functionality  var out = sortBy(  q, 's' );

Answer (score -1):

```
var out = q.sort(function (a,b){
    if (a.o!=null && b.o!=null){
        return a.o-b.o;  
    }
    return a.s>b.s?1:-1;
});
```